# Adding and removing sprites

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I was wondering if it was possible to have two of the same sprites on screen at once. My issue is with clouds. I have two cloud sprites moving across the screen. Cloud1 and Cloud2. I want another Cloud1 to spawn when the first Cloud1 is in the middle of the screen. Also I want the first Cloud1 to be removed after it reaches the end of the screen. Is that possible to do using sprites or would I need to use textures?

```
   override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

   var moveCloud1 = SKAction.moveByX(-CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)*3, y:0, duration: 45)
   var moveCloud2 = SKAction.moveByX(-CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)*3, y:0, duration: 60)

   if(cloudSprite1.frame.origin.x < self.frame.size.width/2){
    let cloudSprite1a = SKSpriteNode(texture: cloudTexture1)
    self.addChild(cloudSprite1a)
    cloudSprite1a.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)*2.4,   y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)*1.8);
    cloudSprite1a.size = CGSize(width: 75, height: 60)

    cloudSprite1a.runAction(moveCloud1)

   }
   }
```

.

```
self.addCloudSprite1(CGPointMake(100, 500))
    self.addCloudSprite2(CGPointMake(100, 300))




}





func addCloudSprite1(position : CGPoint)
{

    cloudSprite1a.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)*2.4, y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)*1.8);
    self.addChild(cloudSprite1a)

    var moveCloud1 = SKAction.moveByX(-CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)*2.8, y:0, duration: 40)
    cloudSprite1a.runAction(moveCloud1, completion: { () -> Void in
        cloudSprite1a.removeFromParent()
        self.addCloudSprite1(position)
    })
}

func addCloudSprite2(position : CGPoint)
{

    cloudSprite2a.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)*2.4, y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)*1.5);
    cloudSprite2a.size = CGSize(width: 75, height: 60)
    self.addChild(cloudSprite2a)

    var moveCloud2 = SKAction.moveByX(-CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)*2.6, y:0, duration: 60)
    cloudSprite2a.runAction(moveCloud2, completion: { () -> Void in
        cloudSprite2a.removeFromParent()
        self.addCloudSprite2(position)
    })
}
```

Comment: sprites display textures, the question indicates you confuse what sprites and textures are. Just create another cloud sprite the same way you created the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load `cloud1` and cloud2 as `textures` and set them to `SpriteNodes` and reuse the same textures as much as you need.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let cloudTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "cloud1.png")
    let cloudSprite1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: cloudTexture1)
    cloudSprite1 // positioned in middle.
    let cloudSprite2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: cloudTexture1)
    cloudSprite1 // positioned in at starting.
}
```

You can do a bounds check inside the update function to add a new cloud sprite.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if (self.cloudSprite1.position.x < - self.cloudSprite1.size.width)
    {
        cloudSprite1.position = //The other end.
    }
    if (self.cloudSprite2.position.x < -self.cloudSprite2.size.width)
    {
        cloudSprite2.position = /The other end.
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can also use SKAction completion handler of the node.

```
func addCloudSprite(position : CGPoint, delay: NSTimeInterval)
{
    let cloudSprite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
    cloudSprite.position = position
    self.addChild(cloudSprite)

    var action = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(-cloudSprite.size.width, cloudSprite.position.y), duration: 6)
    var sequence = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(delay),action])
    cloudSprite.runAction(sequence, completion: { () -> Void in
        cloudSprite.removeFromParent()
        self.addCloudSprite(position,delay:0)
    })
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.addCloudSprite(CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width+50, 200),delay: 0)
    self.addCloudSprite(CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width+50 , 500),delay: 3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, to remove a sprite, you can do it with this method.

```
self.removeChildrenInArray([cloudSprite1a])
```

As far as I know, it can only be done in an Array so you need the [ ] marks.